# How can I enable a specific textfield using a radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable an 'other text' field when the 'option other' radio button is selected.  I can make this work but the form must include more than one radio group.  When I try to add another radio group my code causes both text fields to be enabled.

How do I make this work for just one at a time?  I looked at adding :eq() to the class but I can't figure out how to make that work.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.textclass').attr({disabled:true,enabled:false});
    $('.radclass.can').click(function(){
  $('.textclass').attr({disabled:false,enabled:true});
});
    $('.radclass.cant').click(function(){
  $('.textclass').attr({disabled:true,enabled:false});
});
  });
</script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="next.php">
<input type="radio" name="grp_one" class="radclass cant" value="option_one" />Option          One<br />
<input type="radio" name="grp_one" class="radclass cant" value="option_two" />Option Two<br />
<input type="radio" name="grp_one" class="radclass can" value="option_other" />Option Other<br />
Other Text: <input type="text" name="text_one" class="textclass"/>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="grp_two" class="radclass cant" value="option_one" />Option One<br />
<input type="radio" name="grp_two" class="radclass cant" value="option_two" />Option Two<br />
<input type="radio" name="grp_two" class="radclass can" value="option_other" />Option Other<br />
Other Text: <input type="text" name="text_two" class="textclass"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign a different identificator to both textfields, for example adding a classname relative at the name group:

```
<input type="text" name="text_one" class="textclass grp_one"/>
```

After that in your script you could identify which group has been clicked and than you can do your activation:

```
$('.radclass.can').click(function(){
    var grp = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.' + grp).attr({disabled:false,enabled:true});
});
```

Here a full example ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/yHLRN/))

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks for the link.  That will work fine for me.  I'm still trying to figure out if there is a way to do this using an index rather than an additional class though.